# posting checkbox to mysql check and uncheck

Tags: php, smarty

Hi guys I currently have a form that consists of a few checkboxes, I am using smarty template along with php. I created a form and give it a value, it posts to sql fine with the box is checked but if I uncheck it, it does not update sql, how can I accomplish this?

smarty code

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="setup" value="Setup"
{if $single_array[i].SETUP
== 'Setup'} checked{/if} onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Setup</b>
</form>
```

I am using smarty IF statement here also because I need it to show a table on the page if the checkbox is checked.

php code:

```
if (isset($VAR['setup']) ) {
$sql = "UPDATE TABLE_TEST SET 
SETUP =".$db->qstr(setup).",
SETUP =". $db->qstr( $VAR["setup"]  )."
WHERE SALES_ID=".$db->qstr($sales_id) ;
```

It updates fine if the form is unchecked but it's is not updating if I want to uncheck it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about giving it a default value of unchecked, or an else statement, like:

```
if (isset($VAR['setup']) ) {
$sql = "UPDATE TABLE_TEST SET 
SETUP =".$db->qstr(setup).",
SETUP =". $db->qstr( $VAR["setup"]  )."
WHERE SALES_ID=".$db->qstr($sales_id) ; }
else
{
// DO OTHER ACTION HERE
}
```

Comment: so I tried that and it keeps on unchecking the box. Is there anyway I can specify a value for unchecked in my template and not php?

Comment: When you post a checkbox it only has a value if ticked. What about something like this:    

    if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) { 
    $variable = ("VALUE CHECKED"); 
    } 
    else { 
    $variable = ("VALUE UNCHECKED");
    }

Comment: thanks again for your reply, I am no php pro but I am getting problems using this, I think it has to do with the "onchange" problem is it keeps on refreshing the page after it submits.